# Validating a JS object with Boolean properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate an object which contains some Boolean properties. The code is suppose to loop in the `validate` object and return `TRUE` if *all* of options are `true` and `FALSE` if *any* of the options are `false`.

```js
var validate = {
  text: true,
  email: true,
  phone: false
};

for (var key in validate) {
  if (validate[key] == false) {
    console.log("Not Valid");
    break;
  } else {
    console.log("Yes Object is Valid");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see apparently I am not getting correct return. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var all_valid = true;

for (var key in validate) {
  if (validate[key] == false) {
    console.log("Not Valid");
    all_valid = false;
    break;
  }
}

if(all_valid) {
    console.log("Yes Object is Valid");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff the only thing that looks wierd is why you assign true to `all_valid`

Comment: It's a default. It will change to false as soon as it finds a false value in the validate object. If nothing is false, then it won't change and the result must be true.  Try to think how a solution would look if I didn't initialize it like that.

Comment: but how wen can set it to be false? I mean from the point of security we need to keep it false unless to be proved that is true am I right?